# deleting using executeUpdate() - grails

Tags: grails, hql

I'm having a problem right now, I have 2 domain classes namely **Doctor** and **Patient**, where they have a 1:m relationship. here's my code for class **Doctor**

```
class Doctor {

String name
String specialization

def doctorService

static hasMany = [patients: Patient]
static belongsTo = [hospital: Hospital]


static constraints = {

    name(blank:false)
    specialization(blank:false)
    patients(nullable:true)
    hospital(nullable:false)
}

String toString(){

    "Doctor ${name} "

}

}
```

-->and here's my code for class **Patient**:

```
class Patient {

String name
String ailment
int age
Date dateAdmit, dateDischarge

static belongsTo = [doctor: Doctor, hospital: Hospital]

static constraints = {

    name(blank:false, maxSize:100)
    ailment(blank:false)
    age(size:1..200)
    dateAdmit(nullable:true)
    dateDischarge(nullable:true)
    hospital(nullable:false)
    doctor(nullable:false, validator:{val, obj -> val.hospital == obj.hospital})

}

String toString(){

    "${name} "

}
}
```

-->
 I wanted to delete a **doctor** who doesn't have a **patient** using **executeUpdate()**. I can select the **doctors** without **patients** using dynamic finders like this.
    _

```
def d = Doctor.findAll("from Doctor as d where not exists" +
    "(from Patient as p where p.doctor = d)")
```

_
seems like that syntax doesn't work in **executeUpdate()**, Im just a newbie in grails. please help me.. thanks...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```
Doctor.executeUpdate('delete from Doctor d where d.patients is empty')
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked, funny thing i did earlier is this and I'm getting errors:
 Doctor.executeUpdate('delete from Doctor d where d.patients = null') 

haha. thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You can also do:

```
def d = Doctor.findAll("from Doctor as d where not exists" + "(from Patient as p where p.doctor = d)")*.delete()
```

Comment: That's quite expensive, loading all the instances just to delete them. What if there were thousands or millions?

Comment: thanks! this one also works! but I think its not advisable to use it if you have a large number of data. but thank you, I also learn something new from your code. :)

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to use the [Hibernate Criteria Builder](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) ?
Much more flexible and maintainable than `executeUpdate()`

```
 Doctor.withCriteria{
   isEmpty patients
 }.each{it.delete()}
```

WARNING : this code is not tested. Do not use in production without testing :-D

But that's the idea

Comment: That's quite expensive, loading all the instances just to delete them. What if there were thousands or millions?